# How can I create some versions of exercises and get the LaTeX file?

Tags: output-formatting, latex

Sometimes, I want to create some versions of exercises with the same content. For example, solve the equations:

1. $x^2 - 5x - 6 =0$;
2. $x^2  +  5x - 6 =0$;
3. $2x^2  +  5x - 7 =0$.

Then I solve each equation in my document.

[image]

How can I create some versions of exercises and get a LaTeX file?

Comment: “to solutions” should be “two solutions”, and the variables should be $x_1$ and $x_2$, not $x_1$ and $x_1$

Comment: The intermediate result for your second $\Delta$ is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(**edit**: added simplification if needed)

This output

[image]

is generated by this code (note: code is written in CODE cell (not INPUT) cell). To copy please copy to code cell, else it will get mis-formatted).

Here is [link](https://12000.org/tmp/step_by_step_solve_quadratic/T1.nb) to notebook also.

To use, add your quadratic equation to the list `eqs` below and run the whole code. It will create file `A.tex` in same folder as notebook. Compile the `A.tex` file using lualatex or pdflatex or any Latex compiler to obtain the PDF showing the step by step solution.

```
eqs={x^2-5*x-6==0,x^2+5*x-6==0,2*x^2+5*x-7==0,Sqrt[2] x^2+x-(Sqrt[2]+1)==0}
toX[e_]:=ToString[TeXForm[e]];
formatA[eqIn_Equal,x_]:=Module[{eq=eqIn,s,lis,a,b,c,discriminant},
    eq=First@eq-Last@eq;
    lis=CoefficientList[eq,x]; 
    Print["lis=",lis];
    If[Length[lis]!=3,Abort];
    c=lis[[1]];b=lis[[2]];a=lis[[3]];
    discriminant=b^2-4*a*c; 
    If[LeafCount[Simplify@discriminant]<LeafCount[discriminant],
        s="\\[\n\\begin{array}[c]{cccccc}\n"<>
          "\\Delta &= b^2 - 4 a c &=\\left("<> toX[b]<>"\\right)^2- 4\\left("<>toX[a]<>"\\right)\\left("<>toX[c]<>"\\right)"<>
          "&="<>toX[discriminant]<>"&="<>toX[Simplify@discriminant]<>
          "\n\\end{array}\n\\]\n";
        discriminant=Simplify@discriminant
    ,
        s="\\[\n\\begin{array}[c]{cccc}\n"<>
          "\\Delta &= b^2 - 4 a c &=\\left("<> toX[b]<>"\\right)^2- 4\\left("<>toX[a]<>"\\right)\\left("<>toX[c]<>"\\right)"<>
          "&="<>toX[discriminant]<>
          "\n\\end{array}\n\\]\n";
   ];
   {s,a,b,c,discriminant}
];

formatB[a_,b_,c_,x_,disc_]:=Module[{s,sol},
      sol=(-b+Sqrt[disc])/(2*a);
      If[LeafCount[FullSimplify[sol]]<LeafCount[sol],
         s="\\[\n\\begin{array}[c]{ccccc}\n"<>
             toX[x]<>"_1 &= \\frac{-b + \\sqrt{\\Delta}}{2a}"<>
             "&= \\frac{-\\left("<>toX[b]<>"\\right) + \\sqrt{"<>toX[disc]<>"}}{2\\left("<>toX[a]<>"\\right)} "<>
             "&= "<>toX[sol]<>" &="<>toX[FullSimplify[sol]]<>"\n\\end{array}\n\\]\n";
         ,
         s="\\[\n\\begin{array}[c]{cccc}\n"<>
             toX[x]<>"_1 &= \\frac{-b + \\sqrt{\\Delta}}{2a}"<>
             "&= \\frac{-\\left("<>toX[b]<>"\\right) + \\sqrt{"<>toX[disc]<>"}}{2\\left("<>toX[a]<>"\\right)} "<>
             "&= "<>toX[sol]<>"\n\\end{array}\n\\]\n";
      ];
      s=s<>"And\n";
      
      sol=(-b-Sqrt[disc])/(2*a);
      If[LeafCount[FullSimplify[sol]]<LeafCount[sol],
         s=s<>"\\[\n\\begin{array}[c]{ccccc}\n"<>
             toX[x]<>"_2 &= \\frac{-b - \\sqrt{\\Delta}}{2a}"<>
             "&= \\frac{-\\left("<>toX[b]<>"\\right) - \\sqrt{"<>toX[disc]<>"}}{2\\left("<>toX[a]<>"\\right)} "<>
             "&= "<>toX[sol]<>" &="<>toX[FullSimplify[sol]]<>"\n\\end{array}\n\\]\n";
         ,
         s=s<>"\\[\n\\begin{array}[c]{cccc}\n"<>
             toX[x]<>"_2 &= \\frac{-b - \\sqrt{\\Delta}}{2a}"<>
             "&= \\frac{-\\left("<>toX[b]<>"\\right) - \\sqrt{"<>toX[disc]<>"}}{2\\left("<>toX[a]<>"\\right)} "<>
             "&= "<>toX[sol]<>"\n\\end{array}\n\\]\n";
      ];
        
      s
];

SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
fileName=FileNameJoin[{Directory[],"A.tex"}]
If[FileExistsQ[fileName],DeleteFile[fileName]];
file=OpenWrite[fileName,PageWidth->Infinity];
WriteString[file,"\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\n"<>
       "\\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}\n"<>
       "\\usepackage{amsmath}\n"<>
        "\\usepackage{mathtools}\n"<>
        "\\begin{document}\n"
];

WriteString[file,"Solve the following equations\n\\begin{enumerate}\n"];
Do[WriteString[file,"\\item $"<>toX[eqs[[counter]]]<>"$\n"],{counter,1,Length@eqs}];
WriteString[file,"\\end{enumerate}\n"];
WriteString[file,"\\begin{enumerate}\n"];

Do[currentEq=eqs[[counter]];
    {s,a,b,c,discriminant}=formatA[currentEq,x];
    WriteString[file,"\\item For the equation $"<>toX[currentEq]<>"$ we have\n"<>s<>
        "The given equation has two solutions\n"<>formatB[a,b,c,x,discriminant]
    ],
    {counter,1,Length@eqs}
];

WriteString[file,"\\end{enumerate}\n\\end{document}\n"];
Close[file]
```

And this is the latex file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Solve the following equations
\begin{enumerate}
\item $x^2-5 x-6=0$
\item $x^2+5 x-6=0$
\item $2 x^2+5 x-7=0$
\item $\sqrt{2} x^2+x-\sqrt{2}-1=0$
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}
\item For the equation $x^2-5 x-6=0$ we have
\[
\begin{array}[c]{cccc}
\Delta &= b^2 - 4 a c &=\left(-5\right)^2- 4\left(1\right)\left(-6\right)&=49
\end{array}
\]
The given equation has two solutions
\[
\begin{array}[c]{cccc}
x_1 &= \frac{-b + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}&= \frac{-\left(-5\right) + \sqrt{49}}{2\left(1\right)} &= 6
\end{array}
\]
And
\[
\begin{array}[c]{cccc}
x_2 &= \frac{-b - \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}&= \frac{-\left(-5\right) - \sqrt{49}}{2\left(1\right)} &= -1
\end{array}
\]
\item For the equation $x^2+5 x-6=0$ we have
\[
\begin{array}[c]{cccc}
\Delta &= b^2 - 4 a c &=\left(5\right)^2- 4\left(1\right)\left(-6\right)&=49
\end{array}
\]
The given equation has two solutions
\[
\begin{array}[c]{cccc}
x_1 &= \frac{-b + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}&= \frac{-\left(5\right) + \sqrt{49}}{2\left(1\right)} &= 1
\end{array}
\]
And
\[
\begin{array}[c]{cccc}
x_2 &= \frac{-b - \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}&= \frac{-\left(5\right) - \sqrt{49}}{2\left(1\right)} &= -6
\end{array}
\]
\item For the equation $2 x^2+5 x-7=0$ we have
\[
\begin{array}[c]{cccc}
\Delta &= b^2 - 4 a c &=\left(5\right)^2- 4\left(2\right)\left(-7\right)&=81
\end{array}
\]
The given equation has two solutions
\[
\begin{array}[c]{cccc}
x_1 &= \frac{-b + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}&= \frac{-\left(5\right) + \sqrt{81}}{2\left(2\right)} &= 1
\end{array}
\]
And
\[
\begin{array}[c]{cccc}
x_2 &= \frac{-b - \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}&= \frac{-\left(5\right) - \sqrt{81}}{2\left(2\right)} &= -\frac{7}{2}
\end{array}
\]
\item For the equation $\sqrt{2} x^2+x-\sqrt{2}-1=0$ we have
\[
\begin{array}[c]{cccccc}
\Delta &= b^2 - 4 a c &=\left(1\right)^2- 4\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\left(-1-\sqrt{2}\right)&=1-4 \sqrt{2} \left(-1-\sqrt{2}\right)&=9+4 \sqrt{2}
\end{array}
\]
The given equation has two solutions
\[
\begin{array}[c]{ccccc}
x_1 &= \frac{-b + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}&= \frac{-\left(1\right) + \sqrt{9+4 \sqrt{2}}}{2\left(\sqrt{2}\right)} &= \frac{\sqrt{9+4 \sqrt{2}}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}} &=1
\end{array}
\]
And
\[
\begin{array}[c]{ccccc}
x_2 &= \frac{-b - \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}&= \frac{-\left(1\right) - \sqrt{9+4 \sqrt{2}}}{2\left(\sqrt{2}\right)} &= \frac{-1-\sqrt{9+4 \sqrt{2}}}{2 \sqrt{2}} &=-1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{array}
\]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see output of pdf file at Delta.

Comment: Please simplify two solutions of the equation `Sqrt[2] x^2 + x - (Sqrt[2] + 1) == 0`

Comment: Delta of the first `Delta = (-5)^2 - 4 (1) - 6` must be `Delta = (-5)^2 - 4 (1)( - 6)`

Comment: At 4th equation, with `Delta = 9 + 4 Sqrt[2]`. Can we write this number equal to `(2 Sqrt[2] + 1)^2`?

Comment: **Can we write this number equal to (2 Sqrt[2] + 1)^2?** I am sure for this specific case. But I did `FullSimplify` and this is what Mathematica returned and that is what I used. If you want to customize things more case by case you could do that.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Question Challenge: **Non-Mathematica Answer.**

I hope this is not against the rules of the site, but I suggest that the best tool for this job is not Mathematica.

If you can compile in LuaLaTeX, the [`luacas`](https://ctan.org/pkg/luacas) package allows you to do exactly this sort of computation / replacement straight in the `.tex` file, with very simple syntax.

And in case you are interested, I am working on a similar system with random generation of quadratic equations, which will soon be available on [GitHub](https://github.com/tytyvillus/laboratoire-didactique).

Comment: Can you give me a text file?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 how do you mean -- a text file of what? of my project?

Comment: A text file answer my question of your project.